# Unable to search for words inside and outside code blocks together

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I searched [pascal user:me](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=pascal+user%3A1149) and [div user:me](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=div+user%3A1149), both returned [one of my answer](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/a/2033), which is exactly what I did intend to find.

But [pascal div user:me](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=pascal+div+user%3A1149) and even [pascal div](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=pascal+div) returned nothing.

After a few tries, the problem seemed to be you can't search for both words inside and outside of code blocks. Is it by design? But it doesn't sound reasonable.

Some test: [`appreciating`](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=appreciatin*)

Comment: From experimentation [`"pascal" div user:1149`](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22pascal%22+div+user%3A1149) does match that post. But any other quotations don't - quoting `div` with or without quoting `pascal` doesn't yield any results. So, it's not even very suitable as a workaround because you need to know the word that's outside a block to quote it. I am also not sure *why* that matches.

Comment: @VLAZ I think it's because code blocks are not stemmed, and everything else are stemmed in the search dataset. For each part of the query separated by a * as its own word, it tries the completely stemmed and unstemmed version, but not mixed stemmedness, and return both results together. So appreciatin* matches appreciating in a code block, but not outside code blocks, where they are stemmed to appreci or something. I chose appreciatin* because for some reasons they decided to not stem -ation and -ative, and the search would return too many results with those two words on meta.so.

Comment: But that's still a bit unreasonable, as I can't imagine pascal being stemmed into a shorter word...

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure that quoting a term does turn off stemming. But then `"div"` should have worked. As I also doubt that gets stemmed. I know code blocks don't quite work the same and are processed a bit weirdly. But I can't remember where that is documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of experimentation suggests it could be because the `pascal div` query is searching for a stemmed term not in the stemmed version of the answer. [SE uses stemming when conducting searches](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283475/9363594), which very roughly means that it shortens terms to the absolute minimum word needed for a family of words. I say very roughly because I'm a programmer not a linguist. [Wikipedia has more on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

However, you can use a wildcard in your query (`*`) to broaden the terms searched. [More on that in the help centre](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/help/searching). Indeed, searching for [`pascal * div`](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=Pascal+*+div+user%3A1149) yields your desired result.

Comment: It solves the problem. But I don't see how the help center could explain it. Asterisks seem to switch between code blocks and surrounding text. [Example.](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/search?q=most+of+the+time+in+practice+the+Euclidean+*+unsigned+euclidean_mod+int+a+int+b+*+This+leads+to+idioms+along+the)

Comment: @user23013 Yeah, I had to do some digging into meta StackExchange and meta stackoverflow to even get an idea of what was happening. It's not very well documented.